Iterate through child elements in robot framework
I have a list of users on a webpage like this


<div id="users">
    <li class="user_list">
        <div class="users-name">User One</div>
        <div class="other details">...</div>
    </li>
    <li class="user_list">
        <div class="users-name">User Two</div>
        <div class="other details">...</div>
    </li>
</div>



I want to iterate through the list and get the names of the users like this
@{users_list}=    Get WebElements    xpath=//li[contains(@class, 'user_list')]
FOR    ${user}    IN    @{users_list}
    ${name_el}=    Get WebElement    xpath=${user}/div[@class='users-name']
    ${name_text}=    Get Text    ${parent}
    Log    Name= ${name_text}
END

But I am getting a syntax error that this is not a valid Xpath expression. How can I resolve this? I am using robotframework v7.0 with seleniumlibrary 6.0.


But I am getting a syntax error that this is not a valid Xpath expression.

That's because @{users_list} is a list of WebElement objects, and when you pass a member here:
${name_el}=    Get WebElement    xpath=${user}/div[@class='users-name']

, the argument that gets to the keyword is the concatenation of such object (its string representation, really), and a string.
That's hardly a valid locator, thus the error.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to just use a locator that will directly return all elements you're after:
@{users}=    Get WebElements    xpath=//li[contains(@class, 'user_list')]/div[@class='users-name']
FOR    ${user}    IN    @{users}    
    ${name_text}=    Get Text    ${user}
    Log    Name= ${name_text}
END

